# devtools socket errored Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused(…)

Tags: react-native

Debugging on the device(iPhone) I keep getting this error when debugging.

Note:
1.`AppDelegate.m` & 
2.`RCTWebSocketExecutor.m` urls is set to the right ip, not localhost.
3. and I can get to the bundle from the device.
4. Installed devtool - though I can not see the "react" tab?
5. Deleted the app on the device and restarted after changing the url in Xcode(ref.1).

```
jsSchedulingOverhead (-2ms) should be positive
WarningBox.js:61 

devtools socket errored Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused(…)
```

Comment: I'm getting the jsSchedulingOverhead warning when I use setTimeout in my application. I don't know that it has anything to do with your real issue, which is that it can't connect to your node server. I'd try restarting your node server as well as closing any chome/safari debugging windows

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1598 No need to worry about the jsSchedulingOverhead warning